# Do these SSR terminals have a specific name?

Tags: identification

Right now I examine some SSRs, and most of the samples I have are equipped with these metal "pads", with screws with square washers to squeeze the cable. I know it sounds silly to ask their name, but if they do have a name & are commercially available products it would be appreciated, because then I will be able to prepare a prototype of a product without having to manufacture these parts.

[image: pads]

[image: pads]

Comment: Terminals - Screw Connectors

Comment: Yeah, something like "screw terminals" but chances are they're custom made to fit the case injection molding, or at any rate are quite difficult to source. The top one looks like a much better design. For a few prototypes, just dismantle some SSRs.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany thank you. But why do you think that the top SSR has a better design?

Comment: It looks like it is constrained better from twisting by the feet that fit into the injection-molded part, which keeps excessive force from being placed on the solder joint and PCB when the screw is torqued or when wires are yanked.

Comment: Wurth have some parts that may be interesting as PCB mount power terminals, as IIRC to ERNI, not exactly the same, but maybe good enough for prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

The SSR's in your question are called screw terminal SSR's

the terminals are also a type of screw terminal connector. Those are very hard to find mostly those are custom made according to their mechanical and electrical design (sheet metal work).

Usually Screw terminal type SSR's [to be connected to wire using Lug terminal](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/0e29/0900766b80e29dda.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

"Screw terminal" is the usual name. You can find a pretty decent selection of them from most any electronics distributor, like [digi-key](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/terminals-screw-connectors/396?k=screw%20terminal) or [mouser](https://www.mouser.com/Connectors/Terminals/_/N-5g5u?Keyword=screw+terminal&FS=True), and you might even find them from general hardware or MSC distributors.

Comment: Could whoever downvoted explain why, so that I can improve this answer or, if I drastically misunderstood the question, delete it?